# SQL query works on phpmyadmin but not on php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a strange problem with below sql query.
If I run the query on sql console on phpmyadmin it returns 3 "dimo" vehicle records

```
SELECT * FROM bdata WHERE vehicle LIKE 'dimo%' // returns 3 records
```

but if I make a php file and run it does not return any records but if I change the search to car it shows all the records under car.

Please can someone help I tried many things including changing database structure but did not work. I spent almost a week to fix this issue before seeking help on stackoverflow

```
<?php
    define('HOST','****');
    define('USER','****');
    define('PASS','*****');
    define('DB','*******');

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bdata WHERE vehicle LIKE 'dimo%' ORDER BY vehicle";
    // database has three dimo vehicles but does not show on the php
    // but works fine on phpmyadmin console

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
        echo $row[15];     
    }   
?>
```

Please can someone help

Comment: is there any error? show some code you have tried please.

Comment: You should add error handling to your code. You just assume that mysqli_connect() and mysqli_query() calls are successful.

Comment: if i type 'car%' on php script it works fine

Comment: all calls to connect are successful cos i can search for car, van, mini without any problem

Comment: is your database has a column named  ''15 ''  ?

Comment: i think you need to replace  $row[15]  to  $row['your-table-colunm-name']

Comment: Then remove the where criteria completely and print the `vehicle` field's values out from the php code. Check if there are any values starting with dimo. You may have connected to a different database / host, where the same table does not have entries starting with dimo.

Comment: I have a column 15 and its header is vehicle and it returns all vehicles except dimo

Comment: if i remove 'dimo%' and replace with 'car%' it returns carcarcarcarcarcarcar but i have 3 dimo vehicles but doesnt return on php but returns on phpmyadmin

Comment: @FernandoFrancis check it without  ORDER BY vehicle  statement.

Comment: Then the table you are querying does not contain the records you are looking for. As I wrote before, you may have connected to a different database or host with your php script, that has the same table, but not the same data.

Comment: database im connecting to is 100% accurate and has three dimo vehicles also tried without order by and no luck. Why?????

Comment: i have only one database

Comment: **Note:** Fieldnames returned from `mysqli_fetch_array()`are case-sensitive.

Comment: I do not think this problem can be solved. But thank you for trying. I give up

Comment: if it is case sensitive then why car tuk van and bus works????

Comment: have u tried to fecth results with `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()` ?

Comment: Showing rows 0 -  2 (3 total, Query took 0.0004 seconds.)

SELECT * FROM `bdata` WHERE vehicle='dimo'

id datetime bname tuknumber color telephone nic dvln online latsp longsp town photo suspended rank vehicle booked pwrd email registered account rates susreason demo minrates lastonline 
268 2017-04-02 01:59:24 SureshAlahakoon CPDAP1114 RED 0757854225   0 7.314900 80.653877   0  DIMO 0 183281602182363 suresh.bandara2014@gmail.com 1 facebook 100.00  0 10.00 2017-04-13 19:30:12

Comment: @FernandoFrancis are u answering my question?

Comment: with fetch_assoc and 'dimo%' --> nothing comes up but     with fetch_assoc and 'car%' --> Notice: Undefined offset: 15 in /home/u328267984/public_html/dimotest.php on line 27   i think we are getting somewhere

Comment: try this :     LIKE '%dimo%'

Comment: no luck with '%dimo%'

Comment: how to check this statement works please $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);    cos with 'dimo%' it doesnt work but with 'car%' it works why?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile  using fetch_assoc just means that you can retrieve values by field name only. By confirming that the code works with ` 'car%'`, Fernando answered your question even before you asked it...

Comment: Check `$res`'s value after the mysqli_query() call

Comment: yes with car% it works fine but with dimo% nothing although database has 3 dimo records and 3 car records

Comment: echo $res; can not convert to string can you help Shadow

Comment: Pls check out mysqli's own documentation how to check for errors: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: please shadow can you tell me how to return false when mysqli_query does not connect. I checked the manual but its so comlicated

Comment: how to easily check the $res value after a query with echo?